# Cache linked articles locally?

Tags: feature-request

For questions or articles that link to a website, I think a good feature would be to crawl that site for future usage.

For instance

[How to keep ASP.NET assemblies in AppDomain alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838318/how-to-keep-asp-net-assemblies-in-appdomain-alive)

The top answer links to a C# file, but now the site is down.

When having a url in the question or answer, add the ability to look if google,bing,yahoo,other cache,archive.org has the site, if not then crawl the site with 1 depth to get the content on the page and one layer deep.

Just a thought :)

Comment: I'm not sure about 1 layer deep, but it might not be a bad idea. Either way, though, it's important that this doesn't replace people either (1) summarizing the key points of the article or (2) quoting key passages that explicitly answer the question without pasting the whole article.

Comment: Unless I'm linking back to SO to answer a question, I always try to summarize the link's content and include a code snippet. Editors can always go back in and link to a version of the article cached on archive.org. SO shouldn't get into the business of caching articles.